# Ruby on Rails: How do you check if a file is an image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How would you check if a file is an image? I'm thinking you could use an method like so:

```
def image?(file)
  file.to_s.include?(".gif") or file.to_s.include?(".png") or file.to_s.include?(".jpg")
end
```

But that might be a little inefficient and not correct. Any ideas?

(I'm using the paperclip plugin, btw, but I don't see any methods to determine whether a file is an image in paperclip)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would use the [ruby-filemagic](https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-filemagic) gem which is a Ruby binding for [libmagic](http://www.darwinsys.com/file/).

Comment: The file command is really great for this, so this wrapper should do the job.

Answer (score 17):

Please check it once

```
MIME::Types.type_for('tmp/img1.jpg').first.try(:media_type)
=> "image"

MIME::Types.type_for('tmp/img1.jpeg').first.try(:media_type)
=> "image"

MIME::Types.type_for('tmp/img1.gif').first.try(:media_type)
=> "image"

MIME::Types.type_for('tmp/ima1.png').first.try(:media_type)
=> "image"
```

Comment: I don't know why you got downvoted but this works absolutely fine in Rails 5.0 ! Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

One approach is to use the "magic number" convention to read the first bits of a file.

http://www.astro.keele.ac.uk/oldusers/rno/Computing/File_magic.html

Examples:

```
  "BM" is a Bitmap image
  "GIF8" is a GIF image
  "\xff\xd8\xff\xe0" is a JPEG image
```

Example in Ruby:

```
  def bitmap?(data)
    return data[0,2]=="MB"
  end

  def gif?(data)
    return data[0,4]=="GIF8"
  end

  def jpeg?(data)
    return data[0,4]=="\xff\xd8\xff\xe0"
  end

  def file_is_image?(filename)
    f = File.open(filename,'rb')  # rb means to read using binary
    data = f.read(9)              # magic numbers are up to 9 bytes
    f.close
    return bitmap?(data) or gif?(data) or jpeg?(data)
  end
```

Why use this instead of the file name extension or the filemagic module?

To detect the data type before writing any data to disk. For example, we can read upload data stream before we write any data to disk. If the magic number doesn't match the web form content type, then we can immediately report an error.

We implement our real-world code slightly differently. We create a hash: each key is a magic number string, each value is a symbol like :bitmap, :gif, :jpeg, etc.

Comment: Another approach at checking `jpeg?` would be `return data[0,3].bytes == [255, 216, 255]`

Answer (score 7):

Since you're using Paperclip, you can use the built in "validates_attachment_content_type" method in the model where "has_attached_file" is used, and specify which file types you want to allow.

Here's an example from an application where users upload an avatar for their profile:

```
has_attached_file :avatar, 
                  :styles => { :thumb => "48x48#" },
                  :default_url => "/images/avatars/missing_avatar.png",
                  :default_style => :thumb

validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => ["image/jpeg", "image/pjpeg", "image/png", "image/x-png", "image/gif"]
```

The documentation is here http://dev.thoughtbot.com/paperclip/classes/Paperclip/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 3):

I honestly think this is way easier, use mimemagic gem:

First install it

`gem 'mimemagic'`

Open stream(bytes of target image)

```
url="https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/rbIAAOSwojpgyQz1/s-l500.jpg"
result = URI.parse(url).open
```

Then check data-stream's file type

For example:

`MimeMagic.by_magic(result).type == "image/jpeg"`

Even though this might be more elegant

`%w(JPEG GIF TIFF PNG).include?(MimeMagic.by_magic(result).type)`

Answer (score 1):

imagemagick has a command called identity that handles this - check w/ the paperclip documentation - there's probably a way to handle this from within your RoR app.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to Joel's answer, in Rails 5 I had to transform the comparison string to a bytecode.
Eg:

```
def jpeg?(data)
  return data[0,4]=="\xff\xd8\xff\xe0".b
end
```