# Rails and carrierwave - images can be uploaded but pdf's can't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, carrierwave, minimagick

I have successfully used carrier wave to upload image files.  I want the form to be able to accept image files and pdf's.  When I try to upload a pdf, it does not upload the file.  It has to do with the line:

```
process :resize_to_fill => [166,166]
```

If I take that out, pdf's work.  The problem is I need that line because I need all pictures uploaded need to be resized.
Here is the uploader:

```
class PortfoliofileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
      include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
      def store_dir
          "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
      end
      version :picture do
           process :resize_to_fill => [166,166]
      end
      def extension_white_list
          %w(jpg jpeg gif png pdf doc docx)
      end
end
```

Does anyone know how I can fix it so images and pdf's will work?  Thanks.

UPDATE:

Portfolio show page (2 versions):

version 1:

```
<% @portfolio.portfolio_pics.collect{|picture| picture.port_pic.picture}.each do |pic| %>                           
    <li><a href="#"><%= image_tag pic %></a></li>                       
<% end %>
```

version 2:

```
<% @portfolio.portfolio_pics.each do |pic| %>
    <li><a href="#"><%= image_tag pic.port_pic.picture %></a></li>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Carrierwave has a solution to that, pointed in the [Readme](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave):

## Conditional versions

Occasionally you want to restrict the creation of versions on certain properties within the model or based on the picture itself.

```
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  version :human, :if => :is_human?
  version :monkey, :if => :is_monkey?
  version :banner, :if => :is_landscape?

protected

  def is_human? picture
    model.can_program?(:ruby)
  end

  def is_monkey? picture
    model.favorite_food == 'banana'
  end

  def is_landscape? picture
    image = MiniMagick::Image.open(picture.path)
    image[:width] > image[:height]
  end

end
```

### Example

For example, to create thumbs only for images I adopted this option:

```
version :thumb, :if => :image? do
    process :resize_to_fit => [200, 200]
  end

protected    

    def image?(new_file)
      new_file.content_type.start_with? 'image'
    end
```

In this case make sure you include the MimeTypes:

```
include CarrierWave::MimeTypes
```

Comment: That worked!  I did not even need to include Mimetypes.  How did that work though?  None of the files actually start with the string 'image'

Comment: There's a actually one thing that still doesn't work with this.  When i try to loop through only pictures in the portfolio show page, it still includes pdf's and includes a question mark image for the pdf.  How do I make it only show the pdf?  I'll add my loop through code into the content.

Comment: For the first comment, it doesn't look for 'string' in the image filename, but in the file content_type. PDF files won't have 'image' in the content type.

Comment: If this response worked, could you marked it as solved? :)

As for the second comment, it is another issue. You could ask again if the file is an image looking at the content_type. I don't remember how to do it exactly now, you could always google it. If I can I'll look it up later.

Comment: I would use your second version. You can use the response for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224379/ruby-on-rails-how-do-you-check-if-a-file-is-an-image) to check if the file is an image.